# How can I setup the permissions in Linux so that two users can update the same SVN working copy on the server?

Tags: linux, svn, permissions

My server has both Subversion and Apache installed, and the Apache web directory is also a Subversion working copy. The reason for this is that the simple command `svn update /server/staging` will deploy the latest source to the staging server.

Apache public web directory: `/server/staging` *— (This is an SVN working copy.)*

I have two users on my server, 'richard' and 'austin'. They both are members of the 'developers' group. I recursively set permissions on the /server directory to richard:developers, using "sudo chown -R richard:developers /server".

I then set the permissions to read, write and execute for both 'richard' and the 'developers' group.

So surely, 'austin' should now be able to use the `svn update /server/staging` command? However, when he tries, he gets the error:

```
svn: Can't open file '/server/staging/.svn/lock': Permission denied
```

If I recursively change the owner of /server to austin:developers, he can run the command just fine, but then 'richard' can't.

How do I fix the problem? I want to create a post-commit hook with to automatically deploy the staging site when files are committed, but I can't see a way for that to work for both users. The hook would be:

```
/usr/bin/svn update /server/staging
```

Using the same user account for both of them wouldn't really be an acceptable solution, and I'm not aware of any way to run the command inside the hook as 'root'.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If I were you, I would do a lot of `ls -l` checking to make sure that the permissions look like what you think they do.  It's always possible that you mistyped that chmod or hit 755 instead of 775.  If you've already done this, no offense intended--it just never hurts to double-check!

Comment: Completely agree, but it doesn't seem to be that. The actual /server/staging/.svn/lock file doesn't actually exist until things start happening in subversion, so I'm wondering if this is simply a case of adding a particular user to the developers group. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure, but: If richard and austin are accessing it via HTTP and not via the filesystem, then the www-data or corresponding Apache username needs to be added to the dev group, since it's creating the lockfile.

Comment: Not an answer to the actual question. However, I'd like to comment on your strategy. Instead of a post-commit hook for the developers, I would create a separate user and run any CI program (CruiseControl for example) as that user and monitor the SVN with it.

Comment: Already tried, it didn't work. :( Actually, do I need to restart the server before the new group takes effect? I'll try that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Directory Set Group ID

If the setgid bit on a directory entry is set, files in that directory will have the group ownership as the directory, instead of than the group of the user that created the file.

This attribute is helpful when several users need access to certain files. If the users work in a directory with the setgid attribute set then any files created in the directory by any of the users will have the permission of the group. For example, the administrator can create a group called spcprj and add the users Kathy and Mark to the group spcprj. The directory spcprjdir can be created with the set GID bit set and Kathy and Mark although in different primary groups can work in the directory and have full access to all files in that directory, but still not be able to access files in each other's primary group.

The following command will set the GID bit on a directory:

```
chmod g+s spcprjdir
```

The directory listing of the directory "spcprjdir":

```
drwxrwsr-x 2 kathy spcprj 1674 Sep 17 1999 spcprjdir
```

The "s'' in place of the execute bit in the group permissions causes all files written to the directory "spcprjdir" to belong to the group "spcprj" .

edit: source = [Linux Files and File Permissions](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugfilesp.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would set up `svnserve` which is a simple Subversion server using the `svn://` protocol. You can set this up so it runs under its own user account, then the repository would only be accessed by that one user. This user could then have the correct privileges to run `svn update /server/staging` on a post-commit hook.

Answer (score 0):

in your svn repo, you can find a 'conf' directory where you set permissions. you have 3 files there:

- authz
- passwd
- svnserve.conf

you set in the authz file which users have which kind of acces, per user or per group. you set groups there, SVN groups not linux user groups (hashed lines are comments):

```
[groups]
# harry_and_sally = harry,sally
projectgroup = richard,austin

# [/foo/bar]
# harry = rw  -- user harry has read/write access
# * =  -- everybody have no access

# [repository:/baz/fuz]
# @harry_and_sally = rw  -- harry_and_sally group members have read/write access
# * = r  -- everyone has read access

[/server/staging]
@projectgroup = rw
* = r
```

work around this example and set your config. in the 'passwd' file you set up users passwords. execute

```
cat passwd
```

you'll get commented file with explanation how to set it up.

Comment: I thought that without this, every user has read/write access to every file.  Will this really resolve a permission denied error...?

Comment: Also, aren't the groups for repository access? I'm talking about permission problems with a working copy, not the repository itself.

Comment: @max . this is how i set things up with svnserve in my repos, but using the repo path (the 2nd example in the file with [repository:...].

Answer (score 0):

I use WebDAV - all SVN updates and commits are handled via apache and I never have such problems.