# svn unix permissions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to set up an `svn` repository on a linux server. What permissions do I need to set so users within a group are able to `checkout/update/add` to the repository using their unix login/password over `ssh` on `TotoiseSVN`? I tried setting `770` and it does not seem to work.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164597/how-can-i-setup-the-permissions-in-linux-so-that-two-users-can-update-the-same-sv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions are correct. TortoiseSVN was simply asking for login multiple times (basically each request it had to make to the server). So I am now using a private key based authentication using Putty/Pageant and TortoisePlink.exe.

Comment: First time I've seen something answer their own question, even when no other answers had been given yet.  Nice progress!

Comment: Yeah, well I kept tinkering around after asking this question and figured it out before anyone else answered it.